# Tweepy: Twitter error response: status code = 500

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, hashtag

I'm currently trying to get all the tweets of a given hashtag using tweepy cursor. To achieve this, I created the function below which takes as argument a particular hashtag and writes in a csv file the timestamp of the hashtag and the number of followers of the user.
For some hashtags, this works fine and I got the results I need (hashtags occurrences over a 7 days period - 168 h) e.g. for #promotion. For some others, the executions stops after approx 6 hours giving the error below e.g. #WorldEmojiDay or #marketing. I already seached what the error means and I can't find out how to handle it... Any help would be much appreciated.

## Procedure code:

```
def hashtag_collect(hashtag_name):

    consumer_key='xxx'
    consumer_secret='xxx'
    access_token='xxx'
    access_token_secret='xxx'

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

    # Open/Create a file to append data
    csvFile = open('data_collect.csv', 'a')
    time_followers = open(('collect_17-07/time_and_followers_%s.csv' % hashtag_name), 'a')
    #Use csv Writer
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
    csvWriter_data= csv.writer(time_followers)
    csvWriter_data.writerow(['timestamps','followers'])

    print(hashtag_name)
    dates=['2018-07-12','2018-07-13','2018-07-14','2018-07-15','2018-07-16','2018-07-17','2018-07-18','2018-07-19']
    #print(hashtag_name)
    for i in range(0,len(dates),1):
        print(i,dates[i])
        for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=hashtag_name,count=200,since="2018-07-09", lang='en').items(): #nb: date au format Year-month-day
            #print(i, dates[i])
            csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8'),tweet.user.followers_count, time.mktime(time.strptime(str(tweet.created_at),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))]) #write date, tweet, nb of followers, timestamp
            csvWriter_data.writerow([time.mktime(time.strptime(str(tweet.created_at),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),tweet.user.followers_count])
```

## Error returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "collect.py", line 59, in <module>
    hashtag_collect(tag)
  File "collect.py", line 33, in hashtag_collect
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=hashtag_name,count=200,since="2018-07-09", lang='en').items(): #nb: date au format Year-month-day
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 49, in __next__
    return self.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 197, in next
    self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 108, in next
    data = self.method(max_id=self.max_id, parser=RawParser(), *self.args, **self.kargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 250, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 234, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 500
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an internal service issue per 
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes.html

Not much you can do besides try again later.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)